# Image Thumbnail to Autoplay Video On Hover

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to make image thumbnails for my php project that automatically change to a playing video on mouse hover and goes back to image using javascript. Something like this example: https://store.steampowered.com/labs/microtrailers?flavor=fire_hose_roguelike_3_pages

Unfortunately for some reason, it's not working properly. The video only autoplays sometimes on Chrome after some clicks and seems even less responsive on Firefox... Also the transition between image and video it's not really working...

I followed many examples and StackOverflow answers and nothing seems to work properly. Any ideas how I can make this work?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="card">
         <img class="card-top" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2187966/pexels-photo-2187966.jpeg" alt="">
         <video class="isvideo" loop preload="none">
      <source src="https://dl5.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm" type="video/webm">
    </video>
</div>

<script>
$('.card').hover(hoverVideo, hideVideo);

function hoverVideo(e) {  
        $('video', this)[0].play(); 
        $('.card-top').hide();
    }

    function hideVideo(e) {
        $('video', this)[0].pause();
        $('.card-top').show();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code throws the following exception:

> play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document
>   first.

Chrome has [changed it's policy about autoplaying videos](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes), but it is stated that "Muted autoplay is always allowed.". As such you can make the video play without sound, by adding the `muted` attribute to the video tag, like this:

```js
$('.card').hover(hoverVideo, hideVideo);

function hoverVideo(e) {
  $('video')[0].play().catch(function(e) {
  console.log(e.message);
  }); 
  $('.card-top').hide();
}

function hideVideo(e) {
  $('video')[0].pause();
  $('.card-top').show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
         <img class="card-top" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2187966/pexels-photo-2187966.jpeg" alt="">
         <video class="isvideo" loop preload="none" muted>
      <source src="https://dl5.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm" type="video/webm">
    </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Claudio, the code is working, quick question, how I can make this code work with a list of different thumbnails like this example: https://store.steampowered.com/labs/microtrailers?flavor=fire_hose_roguelike_3_pages Any idea?

Comment: @ramenknight You have to apply the events by class, check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/of0upeyr/6/)

Comment: Wow thank you so much Claudio, I was not going to be able to get there by myself.